# Optimization of while a loop reading a dictionary

Tags: regex, perl, dictionary, while-loop

Hello every one this is my first question here, 
I'm using an open source program called MElt which lemmatize (give the lemma example:giving-->give) of words. MElt works on linux and its programmed in Perl and Python.
So far it's working good but it take way too much time to give the results.
I looked into the code and located the loop responsible for this:

```
while (<LEFFF>) { 
  chomp;
  s/ /_/g;
#  s/(\S)-(\S)/\1_-_\2/g;
  /^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)(\t|$)/ || next;
  $form = $1; $cats = $2; $lemma = $3;
  #print "$form \n";
  #print "$cats \n";
  #print "$lemma \n";
  if ($lower_case_lemmas) {
    $lemma = lc($lemma);
  }
  if ($it_mapping) {
    next if ($form =~ /^.+'$/);
    next if ($form eq "dato" && $lemma eq "datare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "stato" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "stata" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
    next if ($form eq "parti" && $lemma eq "parto"); # bourrin
    if ($cats =~ /^(parentf|parento|poncts|ponctw)$/) {$cats = "PUNCT"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(PRO)$/) {$cats = "PRON"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(ARTPRE)$/) {$cats = "PREDET"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(VER|ASP|AUX|CAU)$/) {$cats = "VERB"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(CON)$/) {$cats = "CONJ"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(PRE)$/) {$cats = "PREP"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(DET)$/) {$cats = "ADJ"}
    if ($cats =~ /^(WH)$/) {$cats = "PRON|CONJ"}
    next if ($form =~ /^(una|la|le|gli|agli|ai|al|alla|alle|col|dagli|dai|dal|dalla|dalle|degli|dei|del|della|delle|dello|nei|nel|nella|nelle|nello|sul|sulla)$/ && $cats eq "ART");
    next if ($form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ && $cats eq "ADJ");
    next if ($form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ && $cats eq "PRON");
    next if ($form =~ /^quell[aei]$/ && $cats eq "ADJ");
    next if ($form =~ /^quell[aei]$/ && $cats eq "PRON");
    next if ($form =~ /^ad$/ && $cats eq "PREP");
    next if ($form =~ /^[oe]d$/ && $cats eq "CONJ");
  }
  $qmlemma = quotemeta ($lemma);
  for $cat (split /\|/, $cats) {
    if (defined ($cat_form2lemma{$cat}) && defined ($cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form}) && $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} !~ /(^|\|)$qmlemma(\||$)/) {
      $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} .= "|$lemma";
    } else {
      $cat_form2lemma{$cat}{$form} = "$lemma";
      $form_lemma_suffs = "@".$form."###@".$lemma;
      while ($form_lemma_suffs =~ s/^(.)(.+)###\1(.+)/\2###\3/) {
    if (length($2) <= 8) {
      $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{$3}++;
      if ($multiple_lemmas) {
        $cat_formsuff_lemmasuff2count{$cat}{$2}{__ALL__}++;
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the variable LEFFF is a dictionary composed of 490489 line. so the loop is comparing the words with all the dictionary lines one by one. this is really really to much.
Any ideas how to optimize this?
Thank you.
Med.

Comment: You'd better to post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OP has now [posted on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/optimization-of-a-while-loop-searching-for-words-in-a-dictionary/30317).

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line `/^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)(\t|$)/ || next;` to:

```
/^([^\t]++)\t([^\t]++)\t([^\t]++)(\t|$)/ || next;
```

for the next regexes, remove all uneeded capturing parenthesis.

`/^(parentf|parento|poncts|ponctw)$/` to

```
/^parent[fo]|ponct[sw]$/   or why not   /^p(?>arent[fo]|onct[sw])$/
```

`/^(una|la|le|gli|agli|ai|al|alla|alle|col|dagli|dai|dal|dalla|dalle|degli|dei|del|della|delle|dello|nei|nel|nella|nelle|nello|sul|sulla)$/` to

`/^(?>una|l[ae]|a(?>i|l(?>l[ae])?)|col|d(?>ello|[ae](?>i|l(?l[ae])?|gli))|ne(?>i|l(?>ll[aeo])?)|sul(?>la)?)$/`

(notice: you can improve this line, by reordering, put the most frequent determinant/articolo at the begining)

Try to change this line:

```
while ($form_lemma_suffs =~ s/^(.)(.+)###\1(.+)/\2###\3/)
```

by

```
while ($form_lemma_suffs =~ s/^(.)([^#]++)###\1(.++)/\2###\3/)
```

You can inverse conditional:

```
next if ($form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ && $cats eq "ADJ");
```

to

```
next if ($cats eq "ADJ" && $form =~ /^quest[aei]$/ );
```

(experimental)You can replace these two lines:

```
next if ($form eq "stato" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
next if ($form eq "stata" && $lemma eq "stare"); # bourrin
```

by

```
next if ($lemma eq "stare" && ($form eq "stato" || $form eq "stata"));
```

Important: With perl, you can compile your regex, it can be useful in your case since you use the same regexes in a while loop. If you do that don't forget to put the regex definitions outside loops! Example:

```
my $regex = qr/^parent[fo]|ponct[sw]$/;
while (<LEFFF>) {
...
if ($cats =~ $regex) {$cats = "PUNCT"}
```

Comment: I tried it but it's still the same thing (I mean the time, the regex is not recognizing words any more).
I think the problem comes from the fact that the program is comparing the hole 490489 word to each word of the sentence, (490489 * 5 words = about 25 million iteration).
the bigger the sentence the more time it takes.

Comment: Re: `/^una|l[ae]|a(?>i|l(?>l[a...` this will actually slow the match down. Simple alternations of constant strings are optimized to a trie data structure which allows extremely fast lookups. The result is similar to the regex you wrote, but runs with much less overhead. The only correct optimization is to remove the `(...)` capturing group (by changing it to a non-capturing `(?:...)`)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers ... I tried what you suggested the program is still running but but the execution time is still the same :(. Even with a pre-compiled regex the program still read all the *500000 entries* in the dictionary (LEFFF). So guys here what I'm thinking now and I would love to have your point of view about it: The LEFFF file (as shown before) is **not even ordered** (so we can apply a **binary search algorithm** on it). Now I have the scripts who generate LEFFF, or I can write a script to order it. My idea is to find a **HASH FUNCTION**, apply it on LEFFF to generate som